# I can't change the size of the radius using input box and button for the user Google Map API

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have the following code and I want to set and change the circle's radius through user's input using input box and button. Any help will be appreciated. EDIT. This is the revised code based on the example provided below but still won't work for me. Every help will be appreciated.

```
<apex:page controller="GeoLocatorController" sidebar="false" showheader="false">

<head>


<style type="text/css">
html { height: 100% }
body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
#map-canvas { width:100%;height:80%; }
.controls    

</style>


<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBJkHXEVXBSLY7ExRcxoDxXzRYLJHg7qfI"></script>


<script>

var circle;


function initialize() {

//Setting default center of the system
var mapCenter = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(36.2048, 138.2529),
    zoom: 18,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

};
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapCenter);

//Get User's Geolocation and Set as the Center of the System
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {

        userLat = position.coords.latitude;
        userLng = position.coords.longitude;

        userLoc = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
        map.setCenter(userLoc);


//User Marker's Image    
var image = 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png';


//Create Marker for the User's Location     
var centerLoc = new google.maps.Marker({
    position : new google.maps.LatLng(userLat, userLng),
    map : map,
    icon: image,
    title : 'Your Position!',
    draggable : true,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
    });


//Create Circle and Bind it to User's Location  
    circle = new google.maps.Circle({
    map: map,
    radius: 100,    // 10 miles in metres
    fillColor: '#AA0000'
    });
    circle.bindTo('center', centerLoc, 'position');
            marker.setMap(map);
    });


function updateRadius(){
var rad = document.getElementById("value_rad").value;
circle.setRadius(parseFloat(rad));
}

}

loadHotels();


}

//Load Records from Cloud    
function loadHotels({Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction('{!$RemoteAction.GeoLocatorController.findAll}',

function(result, event){

if (event.status) {
    for (var i=0; i<result.length; i++) {
        var id = result[i].Id;
        var name = result[i].Name;
        var lat = result[i].Location__Latitude__s;
        var lng = result[i].Location__Longitude__s;
        addMarker(id, name, lat, lng);
    }
} else {
     alert(event.message);
    }
},
 {escape: true}
);       
}



//Create Markers for the Records from the Cloud        
function addMarker(id, name, lat, lng) {

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
        map: map,
        title: name,
    });
    marker.setMap(map);

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
console.log()

</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="googleMap" style="width:100%;height:80%;"/>
<input id="value_rad" />
<input id="radius" type="button" value="Search" onclick="updateRadius()"/>
</body>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: Try to use this `circle.setRadius(parseFloat(rad));` Hope helps @Lawrence

Comment: I tried the code you suggested but nothing happened. Maybe there is something wrong on my way of passing the value of the input box to the radius value of the circle? @simon

Comment: Can you use Jquery ? @Lawrence

Comment: Not that much I am new in using javascript and this is my first project using javascript @simon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this code (it's work), and adapt your code

```js
var user_lat;
var user_lng;

var options = {
    enableHighAccuracy: true,
    timeout: 5000,
    maximumAge: 0
};

function success(pos) {       
   var crd = pos.coords;
   user_lat = crd.latitude;
   user_lng = crd.longitude;      
};

function error(err) {
    alert('ERROR(' + err.code + '): ' + err.message);
};


var circle;
var myCenter;

function initialize() {

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);
    myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(user_lat, user_lng);
    var mapProp = {
        center: myCenter,
        zoom: 15,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myCenter,
    });
    
    circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        map: map,
        radius: 100,    // 10 miles in metres
        fillColor: '#AA0000',
        center: myCenter
     });               
    
    marker.setMap(map);
}

function updateRadius(){
 var rad = document.getElementById("value_rad").value;
 circle.setRadius(parseFloat(rad));
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBJkHXEVXBSLY7ExRcxoDxXzRYLJHg7qfI"></script>


<div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>
<input id=value_rad />
<input id="radius" type="button" value="test" onclick="updateRadius()"/>
```

Comment: I tried the code you made but the radius value still can't be updated through input box and button and the circle still won't show @simon

Comment: See code snippet, and adapt your code with this solution @Lawrence

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I have been working for this for sometime and this is all I need. Really appreciate your help thank you. @simon

Comment: Hi. Sorry to bother you again but I tried to adapt my code into the code you provided but still won't work for me. I have edited my code above into a revised one. Could you please tell me where I went wrong? @simon

Comment: Post snippet @Lawrence

Comment: I am having an error posting the snippet of my code maybe because I am using a controller for cloud database. @simon

Comment: Post code with sample data if you can, like my examle I have put random radius in my circle just for test @Lawrence

Comment: Could you just change the center of the circle to the user's current location on your example instead? @simon

Comment: Can you try my update, my navigator doesn't provide location, so I don't know if it's works, but I have folow firefox tutorial https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition to get navigator location, but the principle remains the same to change radius circle @Lawrence

Comment: I encountered an error. It says ERROR(3): Position acquisition timed out. @simon

Comment: Try to remove `timeout` @Lawrence

Comment: Have you try to use only `geolocation` without `google map` ? @Lawrence

Comment: No this is my first time using geolocation @simon

Comment: I believe that the problem comes to `geolocation`, my code which changes the radisu of the circle works @Lawrence

Comment: Figured it out now. Thanks again. @simon